# Merging branches via Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to merge our master branch into new release branches to see if the release works fine with it (for testing I merge the branches 'master' and 'infra'). I do this with a pipeline script in Jenkins.
However I get merge conflicts in every file that is merged. So for example if the file foo/bar.txt was changed in branch *infra* the result in my local repo looks like this:

```
$ git merge master
Auto-merging foo/bar.txt
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
...
```

Using the below script which is supposed to do the same thing I get the following result:

```
ERROR: Branch not suitable for integration as it does not merge cleanly: Command "git merge --ff c98425e0c22d1ad35749c5eca03ca44652e22c95" returned status code 1:
stdout: Auto-merging foo/bar.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in foo/bar.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I've tried quite a few different settings but wasn't able to make Jenkins merge branches automatically. Here's the part that checks out the repo and should merge it which I created using the snippet generator:

```
checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/infra']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'infra'], [$class: 'PreBuildMerge', options: [fastForwardMode: 'FF', mergeRemote: 'origin', mergeStrategy: 'MergeCommand.Strategy', mergeTarget: 'master']]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<id>', name: 'origin', refspec: '+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master', url: '<url to repo>']]]
```

Edit: I am using a workaround right now by checking out the repo and then running the merge via shell command:

```
checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${buildGitRevision}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'WipeWorkspace']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<id>', url: '<url to repo>']]]
[...]
sh "git merge origin/master"
```

Comment: Neat idea to do test merges. What are the types of conflicts you get? Is it an Auto CRLF thing, or were there substantive hot-patches on `release` that weren't backported into `master`? Project-wide indentation change? I'll write an answer based on the current state of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be conflicts resulting from a merge, it is virtually impossible for you to merge them through an *unattended process*. Manifestly, if there are conflicts, the branch is not ready to merge.

Furthermore, you wouldn't want to resolve merge conflicts via an unattended process: how could you know which version to choose? Yes, you can force git to choose one or the other branch with `git merge master -X theirs` or `git merge master -X ours`, but needing to do this indicates a workflow problem.

Comment: As far as I understood git there shouldn't be a conflict to begin with if a file wasn't changed in both branches but that is the issue I am dealing with here. Merging the test branches on my laptop worked perfectly fine while Jenkins had conflicts in every file that was changed in any of the branches even though the other branch didn't touch the file..